# Limiting table size in mysql, and removing row #1 when new row (above limit) is inserted

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, limit

I have searched for an answer to this, but haven't found one. I apologize if it's already been answered somewhere.

Here's my situation:

There is a table in my MySQL database that I would like to limit to 150 rows. If a new row is inserted after the limit has been reached, I would like to remove row #1, and then insert the new row.

I am using PHP and PDO, if that matters.

I feel like this is a simple question, and I apologize if it's a total noob thing to ask. I'm relatively new to this and I'm just trying to learn.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or explain the syntax I would use for something like this?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the rows in your table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table>
```

Then if that number has reached your limit you can delete a row:

```
DELETE FROM <table> ORDER BY <column> LIMIT 1;
```

And finally you add your new row.

Yes, that's three steps, and that's how MySQL works.

This could go pear-shaped when multiple users access the table, better use transactions and lock the table.

An other approach is needed I think. This is just not what you should do with a database. The better solution would be to limit the rows when you retrieve them:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY <column> LIMIT 150
```

This way you only retrieve 150 rows and this should also solve your problem. Add a harmless DELETE somewhere in your code like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table>
DELETE FROM <table> ORDER BY <column> LIMIT <count-200>;
```

Or any variant of that... basically delete rows that are way to old.

Comment: I think this is exactly what i was looking for.  Thank you! I will give it a try here in a few minutes and see if I can get it working. Again, I appreciate your time!

Comment: You could put above code in a trigger so it get executed automatically when executing the insert.

Comment: @Norbert: Yes, you could, but you're solving the problem at the wrong end. Why not limit when you retrieve rows?

Comment: I've added the delete statement that you specified:  `DELETE FROM <table> ORDER BY <column> LIMIT <count-200>;`

edit -- it actually doesn't seem to be removing any rows. I must have an error somewhere

Comment: The 'count' in the '<count-200>' should come from the SELECT above it, using PHP. You probably also need to `ORDER BY <column> DESC`, so in the reverse order. I'm sorry, that piece of code was a bit cryptic. It basically means you need to delete rows that are clearly too old and will never be used.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware : I read the user question as: Limit the table to X rows all the time, so a trigger with your delete step could achieve that at INSERT all within 1 single action.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware -- Thank you! I was able to achieve the desired result using the methods you provided. I really appreciate your time and expertise. You made this easy!